# WebView: How to Load a specific Link using Default Browser

Tags: android, android-webview

by default, WebView opens all types of links to load in the WebView

How to open/load all URL in the WebView EXCEPT any URL hosted by WhatsApp? I want this to be loaded by user's Default Browser

I know i should be extending WebViewClient and implementing shouldOverrideUrlLoading . But not sure how.
How does it look like inside MyAppWebViewClient.java, if i create one for such tasks?

Comment: ould you provide in your question  the desired behavior, a specific problem or error and the shortest code necessary to reproduce it in the question itself. Questions without a clear problem statement are not useful to other readers. See: [How to create a Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve)."

Comment: your problem isn't clear enough, if you mean the type of links to open whatsapp app from other apps or websites, you should use their URL formatting which is [https://wa.me/<number>](http://example.com)

Comment: I know the link. I just want that link to load in a browser or my WhatsApp app instead of load in the WebView

Comment: Question edited. Thank You

Answer (score 0):

You can use WhatsApp api to make your Android webview app open WhatsApp
This is an example to send a message through WhatsApp by calling the api

https://api.whatsapp.com/send?phone=phone-number

Hope this helps.
Good luck!

Comment: Thanks. But this doesnt work in  WebView. It still forces the link to load inside the WebView. (Still not opening WhatsApp App)

Comment: Try this in your anchor tag  <a href="intent://send?text=Tester#Intent;scheme=whatsapp;package=com.whatsapp;end">